# Ruby error : Cannot load such file

Tags: ruby

I am ruby beginner. Two file is here first file attached to second file by using require. But first file does not load.

**first.rb**

```
puts "First File"
```

**second.rb**

```
require 'first'
puts "Second File"
```

**I am getting erro**r:-

```
/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': cannot load such file -- first.rb (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
from second.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Please tell us. How to solve this problem.

Comment: This should work. Look that the files are in same directory and look that you don't have typos in your file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`require_relative "image_utils"`

Based on your Ruby version, using `require` assumes that `image_utils.rb` is in the $LOAD_PATH (this requires additional setup) as Ruby 1.9 has removed the current directory from the load path. Use `require_relative` instead.

Ruby will first try to resolve the file by its absolute path. Then, if it isn't found then it will check on the $LOAD_PATH as mentioned above, if not then it will throw a `LoadError`

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require